# XML encryption address space

Tags: xml, encryption

When doing encryption on an XML element, is the encryption replacing the address space of the xml element? Or does it use a different address space?

I ask this because I am having trouble with referencing an element after decryption, and I am thinking this answer may help. My other question though more specific is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674457/referencing-an-xml-element-after-decryption-bug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be pretty sure that if you have a DOM of the XML, that the references to the elements in the DOM will be invalid after encryption. I haven't seen a library yet that does not alter the "original" tree (even if it doesn't say so explicitly like Apache XML-sec. Of course, they won't magically reappear after decryption.

Could you take a look at the answer your linked question as well?